# Is there better way to add column to two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an two dimensional array as

```
var textarray = [[{ text: 'Content 1' }, { text: 'Content 2' }], 
                 [{ text: 'Content 3' }, { text: 'Content 4' }]];
```

I have a method to add column to matrix in the right as

```
insertColumnAtRight() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.textarray.length; i++) {
      this.textarray[i].push({ text: "" });
    }
}
```

Is there any better way or shorter way to add column to 2 dimension array?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code more concise using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
textarray.forEach(element => element.push({ text: "" }));
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and `concat` will simplify.

```js
var textarray = [
  [{ text: "Content 1" }, { text: "Content 2" }],
  [{ text: "Content 3" }, { text: "Content 4" }],
];

const res = textarray.map((arr) => arr.concat({ text: "" }));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: While it is shorter, it does use more memory than a classical `for` loop. Your solution creates a new array because of `.map()` and then for each row, it creates a new array because of `.concat()`. So in the result, instead of just adding a new column to existing matrix, you create another matrix that has one more column. I don't know if OP cares about that but I thought it's worth pointing out.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek, That's right. Good points and Thanks for details.  Another intention in this solution is to avoid `data mutation` (to avoid updating original data)